# How to handle text files for graphs on Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, file, text

I have a bunch of text file to process. I have to make sure to retrieve the text files from a single folder to extract a single line of text each.

This if for Python 2.7, I have already tried functions like "os.Listdir" but problems then happen to try to process these filenames. And I alsy think my code for now is not optimal.

So, I am rather lost because I am new to Python and I am hoping that you can help me.
I will be concise: I must succeed in recovering a single line of text from many files that I would like to put in the form of lists and then make a graph. I've tried different things but none of them was actually a concrete solution.

Answer (score 0):

initiate necessary data structure:

```
someArray = []
```

Iterate over the folder like this and open the current file:

```
for someFile in os.listdir(path/to/dir):
    someHandle = open(someFile)
    lines = someHandle.readlines()
```

Then, get the line you want to process with index x, and store it in preinitialized array

```
    someArray.append(lines[x])
    handle.close()
```

process your data

```
for lline in someArray:
    # do whatever
```